# $(this) selector and his descendant

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Im trying to select a descendant class of `$(this)`.

**Here an example :**

```
<div class="family">
    <div class="brother">CLICK HIM</div>
    <div class="cousin"></div>
    <div class="sister">TO SELECT HER</div>
</div>

<div class="family">
    <div class="brother"></div>
    <div class="cousin"></div>
    <div class="sister">AND NOT HER</div>
</div>
```

I want to click on .brother and want to select his `.sister`!

with the following code I would select the child of `.sister`, but thats not what I want to do.

```
$('.brother').click(function() {
    $('.sister', this).hide();
});
```

could anybody help me?

Comment: You are looking for a sibling. Try with `$(this).siblings('.sister').hide();`. Also, you could do `$(this).next().next().hide()`. Or `$(this).parent().find('.sister').hide()`...

Comment: `.sister` is not a descendant of `.brother`

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
ah, you're right. it's an adjacent isn't it, @RomanPerekhrest ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use jQuery function **[nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)** with a selector :

```
$('.brother').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll( ".sister" ).hide();
});
```

Or jQuery function **[siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** with a selector :

```
$('.brother').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings( ".sister" ).hide();
});
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki thanks for the edit, answer looks much better now